# smooth scroll into view vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently I have the following code to scroll to a div:

```
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
   element.scrollIntoView();
},false);
```

How can I make it smooth scrolling? (no-jQuery, no-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

scrollIntoView has a few options, try this

.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});

I found this info on this site "developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView"

Answer (score 1):

```
function animate(elem,time) {
    if( !elem) return;
    var to = elem.offsetTop;
    var from = window.scrollY;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            window.scrollTo(0,(from+step*(to-from))+1);
            if( step == 1){ clearInterval(timer);};
        },25);
        window.scrollTo(0,(from+1));
    }

var divVal = document.getElementById('yourElementID');
animate(divVal,1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5g4wnj9/

let me know if it helped!

Comment: it's not scrolling, when I click to the button.

Comment: The lack of explanation on this is likely to attract downvotes - it's also bad for those who come by looking for answers in the future. A few comments would be adequate and a short description of how this works.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar: tested the same code on mac browsers . Let me know which browser u r testing on.

Comment: @ivy_lynx : code is self explanatory. Please suggest a edit .

Comment: @rahul_send89 apparently it isn't self-explanatory enough for the OP to get it to work. To repeat my previous suggestion: "A few comments would be adequate and a short description of how this works."

Comment: @NavinRauniyar : it mite be a simple debug problem. rename function name or make a class to fix conflict. cause you are not sharing any code or link , i cannot help you solve your problem.